# Quantidade de números ímpares

Tags: python

Criei uma função que retorna os números ímpares. Como faço para retornar a quantidade dos números, por exemplo 4 ímpares, 3 ímpares, e assim por diante?

```
lista = [1,3,5,7,2,4]
impar =[]

def ehImpar(impar):
    for impar in lista:
        if impar % 2 != 0:
            print(impar)

print(ehImpar(impar))
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando list comprehensions

```
impar = len([i for i in lista if i%2 != 0])
```

Agora caso queira uma função

```
def impar(lista):
   return len([i for i in lista if i%2 != 0])
```

Se quiser ler mais sobre list comprehensions, leia este [artigo](https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/list-comprehensions-no-python)

Comment: Boa, Luis. Obrigado, mesmo!!

Comment: @edtech se a resposta te atendeu considere dar o aceite (cliqhe no "thick sign")

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer um counter.

```
lista = [1,3,5,7,2,4]
impar =[]

def ehImpar(impar):
  impares = 0 
  for impar in lista:
    if impar % 2 != 0:
        impares += 1
        print(impar)
   print(impares " números ímpares")
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Davis.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode alterar a função para adicionar os números impares à sua lista, e ao fim da iteração retornar o tamanho da lista:

```
    for i in lista:
        if i % 2 !=0:
            print(i)
            impar.append(i)
    return 'Ímpares:{}'.format(len(impar))
```